# Java check if a object's method is being in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How to check if a object's method is being used in parallel by other threads?

Comment: log inside it `Thread.currentThread().getId` or something? but *why* is more important - this sounds like an XY problem

Comment: ideally, instead of checking you should guard your method from such access (if required) by using synchronization.

Comment: The answers below tell you how to find out whether more than one thread is in the same block of code _at some instant in time_, but by the time your code is able to act on that information it will be a _different_ instant in time and the result of the test may not still be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have some atomic counter increment every time the method is called and decremented when the method exits. A finally block is required in case an exception is thrown in the body.

```
class Test
{
    private final AtomicInteger fooUsers = new AtomicInteger();

    void foo()
    {
        fooUsers.incrementAndGet();
        try
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            fooUsers.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    // is the method invoked by one or more threads
    boolean isFooBeingExecuted()
    {
        return fooUsers.get() > 0;
    }

    // is the method invoked by 2 or more threads (parallel)
    boolean isFooBeingExecutedInParallel()
    {
        return fooUsers.get() > 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time a method is called, it creates its own set of local fields. This allows method invocations by various threads to be completely independent of each other.

You could set up a volatile instance field of some sort and update it upon entry and exit.